# Display none not working Laravel

Tags: php, jquery

I have a condition, if active is checked then it'll display a text form.

This is my view form code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Active:</label>
  {{ Form::checkbox('active', 0,null, array('id' =>'active_check','class' => 'active_check')) }}
</div>
<div id ="join_date" class="form-group" style="display: none;">
  <label>Join Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    {!! Form::text('join_date', null, array('class' => 'form-control datetimepicker' )) !!}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery toggle and check condition code so far:

```
$('#active_check').click(function() {
    $("#join_date").toggle(this.checked);
    $('#join_date').find('input[type="text"], textarea').val('');
});
var activeCheck = $('checkbox[name="active_check"]');
function checkActive(select) {
    if (select.val() == 0) {
        $('#join_date').hide();
    } else {
        $('#join_date').show();
    }
}
checkActive(activeCheck);
```

The issue is when it is first loaded the join_date form doesn't hide. I need to toggle the checkbox to hide it. Any idea?

Comment: Is it a typo that the closing `</div>` tag is missing for #join_date ?

Comment: @nope, I'm using </div> here. my bad

Comment: what is the value of `checkbox[name="active_check"]` checkbox?

Comment: @ravisachaniya 0, updated thread u can check it.

Comment: @AndrewVanusi you have taken `var activeCheck = $('checkbox[name="active_check"]');` but not name in `{{ Form::checkbox('active', 0,null, array('id' =>'active_check','class' => 'active_check')) }}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple logic:

```
if($('#active_check').is(':not(":checked")')) {//test if active_check is not checked 
 $('#join_date').hide();//hide it
}
$('#active_check').click(function() {
    $("#join_date").toggle();//toggle it
});
```

Comment: it's working but when i save it as active, and try to edit it.
the checkbox checked but didn't show join date.

Comment: what do you mean save it as active?